# How can I use bcp.exe in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, bcp

My objective is to backup data from azure sql database into azure blob storage by using azure function.

Iam able to use bcp in both local computer and azure portal (function app).
But i failed to call after i published to azure function app

SampleCode:-

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        string filePath = "filePatch";
        string FileName = "filaName";
        string arg = @"database.scheme.table out table.txt -c -S tcp:testingServer -UUserName -PPassword";

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        FileName = "bcp";
        startInfo.FileName = FileName;
        startInfo.Arguments = arg;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        process.WaitForExit();

        //upload to blob storage
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("table");

        blob.UploadFromFileAsync(filePath);
        return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult("Return result");
    }
```

Error log:-

- bcpSystem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified
- at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
- at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Sub question:-

1. Is bcp able to copy data into azure blob storage directly?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why don't you try this method instead. Cheaper, easier, no code, not relying on older technoligies (like BCP) that may not be could compatible https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-portal

Comment: Are you sure your bcp file is copied to tr bin folder ?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I do researched data factory too, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Thomas I do not copy bcp to tr bin folder, I will try it later.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use PowerShell instead of bcp to perform backups of Azure SQL databases, and use an scheduled Azure Function to execute the PowerShell script that will perform the backup.

Below sample PowerShell script:

```
$subcriptionId = "******"
$resourceGroupName = "project-tra-rg"

#Sql server and target database
$ServerName = "tra-sql-srv"
$DatabaseName = "tra-db"

#target storage informations
$StorageKeytype = "StorageAccessKey"
$StorageKey = "******"
$storageUriTarget = "https://trastorageac.blob.core.windows.net/backup"

#sql credentials
$pwdClear = "******"
$userName = "admin-tra"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwdClear -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $pwd)

#Backup naming logic
$bacpactName = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.bacpac" -f (get-date)
$uriTarget = $storageUriTarget + '/' + $DatabaseName + '-' + $bacpactName

Login-AzureRmAccount -SubscriptionId $subcriptionId

$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $uriTarget -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password

while ($exportRequest.Status -eq "InProgress")
{
   $exportRequest = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -
   OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
   [Console]::Write(" Export in progress..")
   Start-Sleep -s 10
}

if ($exportRequest.Status -eq "Succeeded")
{
   [Console]::Write(" Export done")
}
```

[This](https://runasync.azurewebsites.net/2018/02/20/automate-sql-azure-backup-using-azure-function-and-azure-powershell/) article will provide you more details.

Comment: True. @Thomas https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitagarwal/2018/01/11/azure-function-apps-trigger-in-azure-sql-sql-server-to-execute-azure-function/

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo Thanks for your answer, I will try powershell too. researching data factory now.